# string join append each element text

Tags: c#

i have array with n-elements;

> var arr = ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3"];

I need such result:

```
{"text":"answer1"},{"text":"answer2"},{"text":"answer3"}
```

Tried sothing like this:

```
string.Join(",", arr);
```

But how add  {"text":" "} to each element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ to select from the array with the additional text:

```
var arrayWithText = arr.Select(a => "{\"text\":\"" + a + "\"}");
var result = string.Join(",", arrayWithText);
```